# Intern.io Single Page Application Functional Testing

Tags: intern

I have a single page application that uses Dojo to navigate between pages.
I am writing some functional tests using intern and there are some niggly issues I am trying to weed out.
Specifically I am having trouble getting intern to behave with timeouts. None of the timeouts seem to have any effect for me. I am trying to set the initial load timeout using "setPageLoadTimeout(30000)" but this seems to get ignored. I also call "setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)" but again this seems to have no effect.

The main problem I have is that it may take a couple of seconds in my test environment for the request to be sent and the response parsed and injected into the DOM. The only way I have been able to get around this is by explicitly calling "sleep(3000)" for example but this can be a bit hit & miss and sometimes the DOM elements are not ready by the time I query them. (as mentioned setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000) doesn't seem to have an effect for me)

With the application I fire an event when the DOM has been updated. I use dojo.subscribe to hook into this in the applictaion. Is it possible to use dojo.subscribe within intern to control the execution of my tests?

Heres a sample of my code. I should have also mentioned that I use Dijit so there is also a slight delay when the response comes back and the widgets are being created (via data-dojo-type declarations)...

```
    define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern/node_modules/dojo/topic'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, topic) {
    registerSuite({
        name: 'Flow1',  
        // login to the application
        'Login': function(remote) {
            return remote
                .setPageLoadTimeout(30000)
                .setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)
                .get(require.toUrl('https://localhost:8080/'))
                .elementById('username').clickElement().type('user').end()
                .elementById('password').clickElement().type('password').end()
                .elementByCssSelector('submit_button').clickElement().end();
        },
        // check the first page
        'Page1':function() {
            return this.remote
                .setPageLoadTimeout(300000)      // i've tried these calls in various places...
                .setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)   // i've tried these calls in various places...         
                .title()
                    .then(function (text) {
                        assert.strictEqual(text, 'Page Title');})
                    .end()              
                .active().type('test').end()
                .elementByCssSelector("[title='Click Here for Help']").clickElement().end()             
                .elementById('next_button').clickElement().end()
                .elementByCssSelector("[title='First Name']").clear().type('test').end()
                .elementByCssSelector("[title='Gender']").clear().type('Female').end()
                .elementByCssSelector("[title='Date Of Birth']").type('1/1/1980').end()             
                .elementById('next_button').clickElement().end();
        },
        // check the second page
        'Page2':function() {            
            return this.remote
                .setImplicitWaitTimeout(10000)              
                .sleep(2000) // need to sleep here to wait for request & response injection and DOM parsing etc...
                .source().then(function(source){
                    assert.isTrue(source.indexOf('test') > -1, 'Should contain First Name: "test"');
                    }).end()
                // more tests etc...
        }
    });
});
```

I'm importing the relevant Dojo module from the intern dojo node module but I'm unsure of how to use it.

Thanks

Comment: Could you please show the code you are using?

Comment: I've just appended some code samples. Thanks!

Comment: Anyone got any ideas? Even taking a step back with this question. The "timeout" settings with the intern WD wrapper don't seem to work to me. No matter what I do I can't get the initial wait timeout for the request to return to differ from the default of 30 seconds. Has anyone even got an example of the set timeout functions working?

Comment: Sounds like you should be using promises for those...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your test is timing out, because Intern tests have an explicit timeout set to 30s that is not accessible through their API. It can be changed by adding `'intern/lib/Test'` to your define array, and then overwriting the timeout from the Test's object, e.g. `Test.prototype.timeout = 60000;`.

For example:

```js
define([
    'intern!object',
    'intern/chai!assert',
    'require',
    'intern/node_modules/dojo/topic',
    'intern/lib/Test'
], function (registerSuite, assert, require, topic, Test) {
  Test.prototype.timeout = 60000;
  ...
}
```

This should change the timeout to one minute instead of 30s, to prevent your test timing out.